# Paste two columns alphabetically in awk

Tags: awk

I have a file which contains columns with letters :

```
1   2
A   C
C   G
T   C
G   C
```

I am looking for a way of creating column `3` which contains pasted two columns in alphabetical order.
I am aware of `sort` , however im looking for a way to do it with `awk`.
Thank you for any help

```
EDIT
```

Here is output im looking for

```
3
A:C
C:G
C:T
C:G
```

Comment: What would be the desired output?

Comment: @SMA, sorry, missed it, i added it to the question.

Comment: @ThePooh, should the output contain only one column or 3 columns?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it would be just perfect if it contains all the columns, but if it is not possible, then its ok to have it separate

Comment: @ThePooh, is it Ok if the output would be `tab` separated?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes it is ok

Comment: @ThePooh, I guess the last line in the output should be `C:G`

Comment: I'd NEVER have guessed from your statement `I am looking for a way of creating column 3 which contains pasted two columns in alphabetical order.` that you actually wanted just 1 column of output like that! [edit] your question so the text and expected output both tell us the same requirement, whatever it is you actually want.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you, but have already found solution.

Comment: This site isn't just for you - it's primarily an archive where someone with a question can search for an existing question and find the answer to their question. So it's important that questions make sense even if you somehow got an answer so people with the same question can find the same answer.

Comment: Thanks, it will be also more nice of you if you can be more polite in your expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***gawk*** approach:

```
awk 'NR==1{$0=$0 OFS "3"}NR>1{ a[$1]; a[$2]; asorti(a,b); 
     $(NF+1)=b[1]":"b[2]; delete a}1' file | column -t
```

The output:

```
1  2  3
A  C  A:C
C  G  C:G
T  C  C:T
G  C  C:G
```

---

- `NR==1{$0=$0 OFS "3"}` - add new field `3` to the *header* line
- `asorti(a,b)` - sort array `a` by indices. `b` is a *destination* array containing sorted indices
- `$(NF+1)` - points to the next after last column

Comment: `asort` is always nice touch. ++

Comment: Oho thank you! it worked! :)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest spasibo bolshoe, vi mne ochen pomogli! :)

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{print $1,$2,((s=$1+$2)?s:($1<$2?$1 ":" $2:$2 ":" $1))}' file
1 2 3
A C A:C
C G C:G
T C C:T
G C C:G
```

The final sort needs to be done by piping to `sort`:

```
$ awk ... | sort
1 2 3
A C A:C
C G C:G
G C C:G
T C C:T
```

Explained some:

- `((s=$1+$2) ? s : ...)` if field values are numbers (in this case the header only, causes problems if data apart from headers is numeric) sum them and print (ie. `1 2 -> 3`)
- `($1<$2 ? $1":"$2 : $2":"$1)` if `$1` is before `$2` in order, print them, otherwise print in reversed order

Comment: But column 3 should be sorted alphabetically

Comment: Posted old version...